# scroll to top react doesn't work with reactdom's findDOMNODE

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.container = document.getElementById('container')
  const containerNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.container)
  if(containerNode) containerNode.scrollTop = 0
}
```

Nothing happens when I apply above code in my component, just curious what's the mistake? I didn't use ref, I need  `document.getElementById('container')` for some other thing.

Comment: can you show that JSX content too

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid using `document.getElementById`. Instead you should probably use `ref` like it is mentioned in the [**docs**](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#adding-a-ref-to-a-dom-element)

```
render(){ 
  <div id="container"
    ref={(container) => { this.container = container; }} 
  />
}
```

And then in the componentDidMount you can do this

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.container.scrollTop = 0
}
```